# Visual Studio 2013 - DB Connection breaks in Debug mode

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I have an issue with Visual Studio connecting to databases when running in Debug mode.

I've a simple Console application that I'm using to connect to a remote SQL Server database. If I compile and run the EXE it connects fine. If I run it in Debug mode I'm getting the below when I try and open the connection.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup.)

Running the below it fails on the Open() command.

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

try
{

    conn.Open();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

}
```

I'm using credentials that I know work. SQL Management Studio connects from my desktop using these credentials without a problem (also creating an ODBC connection works). I've tried the exact same connectionstring in a Web application running locally, and this works fine.
A colleague took a copy of the code, ran it in debug mode mode it works fine for him.

I've tried every combination of Data Source I can think of.
All were also tried in SQL Management studio and worked.

It's like VS is corrupted. I've tried multiple installs of VS 2013 (Professional, Premium) and all have the same problem.

Are there some shared components VS uses that could have become corrupted?
Any ideas?